# Weibull's MLE consistency and asymptotic normality

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, asymptotics, estimators, consistency

Let X = $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ be a sample from Weibull distribution $W(\alpha, \beta)$ with fixed and known $\alpha$. Find MLE of parametric function $g(\beta) = \beta^{\alpha}$. Check if bias is equal to $0$. Show it is consistent and asymptotically normal.

Weibull's density is:
$$
f(x, \alpha, \beta) = \alpha \beta^{-\alpha}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-(\frac{x}{\beta})^\alpha} =
$$
so
$$
l(p) = \alpha^n\beta^{-n\alpha}(x_1 \cdot \dots \cdot x_n)^{\alpha -1}e^{-\frac{1}{\beta^{\alpha}}(x_1 \cdot \dots \cdot x_n)^\alpha} \\
L(p) = n\ln \alpha - n \alpha \ln \beta + (\alpha -1)(\ln x_1 + \dots + \ln x_n)-(\frac{x_1}{\beta})^\alpha - \dots - (\frac{x_n}{\beta})^\alpha \\
(L(p))' = \frac{-n \alpha}{\beta} + \alpha(\frac{x_1}{\beta})^{\alpha-1}\frac{x_1}{\beta^2}+\dots + \alpha(\frac{x_n}{\beta})^{\alpha-1}\frac{x_n}{\beta^2}$$
so
$$
\frac{n \alpha}{\beta}  = \alpha \frac{\frac{x_1^\alpha}{\beta^{\alpha-1}}+\dots+\frac{x_n^\alpha}{\beta^{\alpha-1}}}{\beta^2} \\
\beta n = \frac{x_1^\alpha + \dots + x_n^\alpha}{\beta^{\alpha-1}}
$$
and finally 
$$
\beta^\alpha = \frac{x_1^\alpha + \dots + x_n^\alpha}{n}
$$

so the MLE of g is $\frac{x_1^\alpha + \dots + x_n^\alpha}{n}$.

How can I proceed with calculating bias, consistency or the asymptotical normality?

Comment: Please add `self-study` tag if this is homework. Search for invariance property of MLE. What is $\theta$ here?

Comment: Well, by $\mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta}) = \theta$ I meant the (un)biasedness of the estimator. I need to check if bias is equal to 0.

Comment: So, I need to calculate the MLE of Weibull's and then apply $g(\beta)$ on it?

Comment: I got it - when I calculated the MLE of Weilbull's I got the $\beta^\alpha$ after a while. Thank you for the invariance tip. What about the consistency?

Comment: What is the MLE of $\beta$? Add it in your post.

Comment: I have edited what I've found out so far. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Since $\bar{X} > 0$, what is the sign of $-\bar{X}/\alpha^2$?

Comment: @jbowman $\alpha > 0$ so it is negative. Does that mean $\mathbb{E}(\overline{X}  \frac{-1}{\alpha^2} )= 0$?

Comment: It means you messed up somewhere :), because the MLE of $\beta$ to the anything can't be negative, since $\beta > 0$.

Comment: Here's a hint:  look at $x$ in the exponential term in your first and second lines - the pdf and the likelihood function.   See how the terms differ?  That's a start.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question with newer version.

Comment: $\sum x^a \neq (\sum x)^a$, unless $a=1$.

Comment: Yet another edit done. I am terribly sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Bias is pretty straightforward at this point; derive the distribution of $x^a$ using a standard change-of-variable approach and find the expectation (should be almost immediately obvious.)   You can apply the CLT to the sample mean of $x^a$ to deduce the asymptotic normality.  If the estimator is unbiased, it's consistent too.

Comment: If X is Weibulls then $P(X^\alpha\leq t) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq t^{\frac{1}{\alpha}})$ and taking derivatives w.r.t. $t$ $\frac{1}{\alpha} t^{\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}}\alpha\beta^{-\alpha}t^{\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}}e^{-\frac{x}{\beta^\alpha}} = \beta^{-\alpha}e^{-\frac{x}{\beta^\alpha}}$. Should I calculate $\int x \beta^{-\alpha}e^{-\frac{x}{\beta^\alpha}} dx$ to find the $EX^\alpha$? Is that perhaps a known integral/density?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the comments into an answer:

Density of $X$ is $$f_X(x)=\alpha\beta^{-\alpha}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-(x/\beta)^{\alpha}}\mathbf1_{x>0}\quad;\,\alpha,\beta>0$$

So likelihood function for known $\alpha$ given the sample $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is

$$L(\beta)\propto \beta^{-n\alpha}\exp\left\{-\frac1{\beta^\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^\alpha\right\}\mathbf1_{x_1,\ldots,x_n>0}\quad,\,\beta>0$$

Log-likelihood is $$\ell(\beta)=\text{constant }-n\alpha\ln\beta-\frac1{\beta^\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^\alpha$$

And $$\ell'(\beta)=-\frac{n\alpha}\beta+\frac{\alpha}{\beta^{\alpha+1}}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^\alpha$$

MLE of $\beta^\alpha$ is indeed $$\widehat{\beta^\alpha}(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^\alpha$$

By a change of variables $Y=X^\alpha$, you can see that density of $Y$ is

$$f_Y(y)=f_X(y^{1/\alpha})\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|=\frac1{\beta^\alpha}e^{-y/\beta^\alpha}\mathbf1_{y>0}\quad;\,\alpha,\beta>0$$

So $Y$ is Exponential with mean $\beta^\alpha$.

- For verifying consistency of MLE, use  (weak) law of large numbers.
- For verifying asymptotic normality of MLE, appeal to classical CLT.

As expected in 'regular' cases, MLE is consistent and asymptotically normal.

A brief discussion of consistency and asymptotic normality of MLE can be found [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lecture3.pdf).